# php select value and update value

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

PHP/MySQL (CodeIgniter)

I would like to add new interest_keywords in the exist database value.

here is my code

```
$query = 'SELECT u_interest_keyword FROM '.T_USER_ACCOUNT.' WHERE u_id = "'.$u_id.'"';
$result = $this->db->query($query);

$result_keyword = $result.','.$personal_keyword;

$query = 'UPDATE '.T_USER_ACCOUNT.' SET u_interest_keyword = "'.$result_keyword.'" WHERE u_id = "'.$u_id.'"';
$this->db->query($query);
```

It just replaces a new keyword in the database.

Can you tell me why it doesn't work?

Comment: your question is not clear.. try to tell in complete way..

Comment: $result is not having only `u_interest_keyword`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[$this->db->query](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/queries.html) returns object when read type queries are run.

So, you have to do something like this after $result = $this->db->query($query);

```
$result_row = $result->row();
```

Then Rectify this:

```
$result_keyword = $result_row->u_interest_keyword. ',' .$personal_keyword;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$row = $result->row();
$result_keyword = $row->u_interest_keyword.','.$personal_keyword;
```